# MariaDB INSERT INTO... SELECT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE affecting 0 rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, sql-insert, mariadb

I've created the following table in MariaDB

Table creation

```
CREATE TABLE `email_templates_pending` (
  `template_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `template_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `template_data` text,
  `modify_type` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `modify_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `modify_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`template_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `template_name` (`template_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And inserted a row in that table with the `template_id = 1`. I wanted to update the row using the following `INSERT INTO...SELECT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement below

SQL Statement

```
INSERT INTO email_templates_pending
          (template_id, template_name, template_data,  modify_by,    modify_type) 
    SELECT template_id, template_name, template_data, 'test@test.com', 'Deleted'
        FROM email_templates WHERE template_id= '1' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE modify_type='Deleted'
```

However, when I run the statement it returns successful but with `0 rows affected`. I have another similar table with different column names that works as intended. I've ensured that the template_id is the primary key, so I'm not sure what else the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

You have 1 row in email_templates_pending, but no rows in email_templates.

That may be the reason why 0 row affected. No row is in the source table.

```
INSERT INTO email_templates_pending ...
SELECT ... FROM email_templates
```

If you just want to update for id = 1, you can use this:

```
INSERT INTO email_templates_pending (template_id, template_name, template_data, modify_by, modify_type) 
SELECT template_id, template_name, template_data, 'test@test.com', 'Deleted' FROM email_templates_pending 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE modify_type='Deleted';
```

If you just need to do UPDATE, may be a direct UPDATE statement can also be used.

```
UPDATE email_templates_pending SET modify_type='Deleted' WHERE template_id= '1';
```

Comment: Would it be possible to update the syntax so it doesn't rely on the email_templates table?

Comment: why not just use a UPDATE? @Jester

Comment: The way the code is architected it actually does need to grab the value from the email_template table if it doesn't exist in the email_template_pending table. Are you suggesting to run a second UPDATE statement after the INSERT SELECT?

Answer (score 0):

If id#1 existed *and* was already marked as "Deleted", you would correctly get "0 rows affected".

To prove that this is not the case, let's see the output from

```
SELECT template_id, template_name, template_data,  modify_by,    modify_type
    FROM email_templates WHERE template_id= '1' ;
```